Spotify Web Playback SDK Works on Android and Windows but Not on Mac Chrome or iOS
I'm using the Spotify Web Playback SDK to integrate playback functionality in my app. The setup works perfectly on Android devices and Windows Chrome, but I'm encountering issues on Mac Chrome and all iOS devices.
The SDK seems to fail in initializing or connecting the player on these devices. I've implemented various error listeners (e.g., for initialization, authentication, and account errors), but none of them provide any clues as to why this issue is happening.
Here’s a simplified version of my hook setup for the SDK:
const useSpotifyWebPlaybackSdk = (session: ExtendedSession | null) => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [deviceId, setDeviceId] = useState<string>("");
  const playerRef = useRef<Spotify.Player | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!session?.accessToken) return;

    const initializePlayer = async () => {
      if (!window.Spotify) {
        setInitError("Spotify SDK not loaded");
        return;
      }

      const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
        name: "My App Player",
        getOAuthToken: (cb) => cb(session.accessToken!),
      });

     player.addListener("ready", ({ device_id }) => setDeviceId(device_id));
      player.addListener("initialization_error", ({ message }) => console.error(message));

      await player.activateElement();
      player.connect().then((success) => {
        if (!success) console.error("Failed to connect to Spotify");
      });

      playerRef.current = player;
    };

    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = initializePlayer;

    if (window.Spotify) initializePlayer();
    else {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    return () => {
      if (playerRef.current) playerRef.current.disconnect();
    };
  }, [session?.accessToken]);

  return { player: playerRef.current, deviceId, isReady };
};



